# React-Peity error Cannot read property 'any' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I installed `react-peity v.0-0-1` When I try to import it in the component using:
`import {Line} from 'react-peity';` It throws the error: `Cannot read property 'any' of undefined`

Please help me to solve this issues I need to use peity on my project

Comment: The library is using react version `15.1.0` and you are using a version greater than or equal to `v15.5`. So if you use a lower version of react, it would work

Comment: That is mainly caused because the `Proptypes` has been moved to a separate library since 15.5. So you either downgrade your react version, or you fork and upgrade the library itself.